# Iterating through JSON with jQuery returns number 9 when used in combination with text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "solution": {
        "1": {
            "cell-1": "1",
            "cell-2": "2",
            "cell-3": "3",
            "cell-4": "4",
            "cell-5": "5",
            "cell-6": "6",
            "cell-7": "7",
            "cell-8": "8",
            "cell-9": "9"
        },
        "2": {
            "cell-1": "1",
            "cell-2": "2",
            "cell-3": "3",
            "cell-4": "4",
            "cell-5": "5",
            "cell-6": "6",
            "cell-7": "7",
            "cell-8": "8",
            "cell-9": "9"
        },
        etc...
    }
}
```

I'm making a sudoku game, so there are 9 sections and each section has 9 cells (which contain a number). The puzzle has to be filled in automatically using the above JSON as the data source. My JS to loop through the JSON file and fill in the numbers looks like this:

```
$.getJSON(validSolution, function(data) {
    $.each(data.solution, function(sectionName, cells) {
        var currentSection = $('[data-section=' + sectionName + ']');
        console.log(currentSection);
        $.each(cells, function(cellName, cellNumber) {
            console.warn(cellNumber);
            currentSection.find('[data-number]').text(cellNumber);
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML looks like this (one section as an example, there are 9 of them):

```
<div class="sudoku__body__section" data-section="1">
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="1">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="2">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="3">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="4">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="5">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="6">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="7">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="8">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="9">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number></span>
    </div>                 
</div>
```

The problem is that this code fills every cell with the number 9. With the current JSON file, the output should be like this for every section:

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
-------------
```

However, it looks like this:

```
-------------
| 9 | 9 | 9 |
-------------
| 9 | 9 | 9 |
-------------
| 9 | 9 | 9 |
-------------
```

What's the problem here and how do I fix it? The console returns no errors and all the logs show the correct values. The loops are going perfectly well and I can see the correct sections, cells and corresponding values, but when I use jQuery `text()` or `html()` it just places `9` everywhere.

Comment: `.find('[data-number]')` selects all elements with that attribute. You'll have to be more specific which cell to fill.

Comment: When I do `.find('[data-number="' + cellNumber + '"]')` nothing gets filled in. But again, the cellNumber displayed in the console shows the correct number.

Comment: `data-number` doesn't have a value so why would `.find('[data-number="' + cellNumber + '"]')` select anything? Did you mean `.find('[data-cell="' + cellNumber + '"]')`?

Comment: @JJJ That was the mistake I made. Thanks for pointing it out though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code you have to use:

```
<div class="sudoku__body__section" data-section="1">
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="1">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-1"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="2">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-2"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="3">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-3"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="4">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-4"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="5">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-5"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="6">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-6"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="7">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-7"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="8">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-8"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sudoku__body__section__cell" data-cell="9">
        <span class="sudoku__body__section__cell__number" data-number="cell-9"></span>
    </div>                 
</div>



$.getJSON(validSolution, function(data) {
    $.each(data.solution, function(sectionName, cells) {
        var currentSection = $('[data-section=' + sectionName + ']');
        console.log(currentSection);
        $.each(cells, function(cellName, cellNumber) {
            console.warn(cellNumber);
            currentSection.find('[data-number="' + cellName +'"]').text(cellNumber);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is with this line

```
currentSection.find('[data-number]').text(cellNumber);
```

If all the cells are selected by your find, all the text in them is replaced every iteration.

Maybe you can introduce an index variable like:

```
var i =0;
```

...
and then in the second loop do

```
currentSection.find('[data-number]')[i].innerText = cellNumber;
i++;
```

I know that there is a way to get the index from your for each loop just don't remember how to do it in your context. That way it will be even better as you don't have to introduce a new variable.

Another way without introducing a variable would be changing just one line:

```
 currentSection.find('[data-number]')[cellName.replace("cell-", "") - 1].innerText = cellNumber;
```

Comment: When I do `.find('[data-number="' + cellNumber + '"]')` nothing gets filled in. But again, the cellNumber displayed in the console shows the correct number.